# setstate not working even when using await, advice?

Tags: reactjs, debugging

I am so close to finishing a necessary component of my app; but,For some reason after the object generated it doesn't set the state despite my command to the functions name is handleSearchBar and it works fine up to the set state. Like the comment says please assume the object is made and the variable im trying to get the value out of has the data in set state.

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import axios from 'axios';
import { default as AreaW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/areaMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as CityW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/cityMainComponent.jsx";
import { default  as CountryW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/countryMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as NeighborhoodW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/neighborhoodMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as RegionW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/regionMainComponent.jsx";
import { NavBar } from "../Navbar/navbar.jsx";
import  {MenuList}  from "./MenuList.jsx";
import GeographicLocationSearch from "./geographicSearchBar.jsx";
import { NewObject } from "./newObject.jsx";
class Menu extends React.Component{
    static propTypes = {
        suggestions: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array)
      };
    
      static defaultProps = {
        suggestions: []
      };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Don't call this.setState({) here!
        this.state = { name:null,type:"",supra:{},newObject:"",itemName:"",options:[],searchBar:[{locations:["country","region","area","city","neighborhood"]}]};
        this.handleNavBar=this.handleNavBar.bind(this);
        this.handleSearchBar=this.handleSearchBar.bind(this);
    }

      
        
        //to search by location.
        async  componentDidMount(){
            //set possible options
            let name=this.state.name;
            let category='country';
             await this.setState({type:'country'});   
                if(name){
            
                   await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/'+category+'/'+name)
                        .then(res => {
                         this.setState({options:res});
                        
                        }).catch(
                        function (error) {
                        }); 
                        let newSupra=this.state.options[0];
                        await this.setState({supra:newSupra});
                        let ofSupra=this.state.supra;
                        let children=[];
                        ofSupra.map((e)=>{
                            children.push(e);
                        })
                        await this.setState({options:children});
                    }
                    else{
                        let list=[];
                        await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/'+category)
                            .then(res => {
                           
                                list.push(res);
                            }).catch(
                            function (error) {
                                let x=error;
                            }); 

                            await this.setState({options:list[0].data});
                    }
                   
                 //turn to a list of options 
                
        }
        
      //get search parameters
   async handleNavBar(value){
    let list=[];
    await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/'+value)
        .then(res => {
       
            list.push(res);
        }).catch(
        function (error) {
            let x=error;
        }); 

        await this.setState({options:list[0].data});
        await this.setState({kind:value});
   }
   //this is the function.just assume there is a valid object cause there is.


        async handleSearchBar(value){
 
        await axios.get(
          'http://localhost:8080/'+value.category+'/getById/'+value.id)
             .then(res => { this.setState({supra:Object(res.data)}, () => {
                console.log(this.state.supra)});}).catch(
            
           function (error) {console.log(error)
          }
          );

         

        
    
   }
  render() {
    return(
        <div>
            
            <div>
                <NavBar content={this.state.searchBar} handleNavBar={this.handleNavBar} />
            </div>
            <div>
            { /*this is the call */}
               <GeographicLocationSearch handleSearchBar={this.handleSearchBar}/>
            </div>
            <div>
               
                <NewObject category={this.state.type} key={this.state.supra}/>
           </div>
            <div>
                 <MenuList Items={this.state.options} kind={this.state.type}/>
            </div>
               
           
        </div>
        
    );

};
}
export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot mix between `async await` and `then catch` use one of them:

```
try {
 const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/${value.category}/getById/${value.id}`)
 newObject=res.data
} catch (err) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

also you don't need to `await` for `this.setState` as the state is changed in the end of each lifecycle / method, in case you are accessing the `state` or `props` inside the `setState` you should use the callback like this:

```
this.setState(function(state, props) {
  return {
    counter: state.counter + props.increment
  };
});
```

Comment: unfortunatly i tried it your way and it did not work

Comment: handleSearchBar(value){
 
     

          try{
           let res= axios.get(
                'http://localhost:8080/'+value.category+'/getById/'+value.id);

                  this.setState({supra:res.data});
                  console.log(this.state.supra);
          }
          catch(error){
            console.log(error);
          }

        
    
   }